# HTTP Authentication JAVA

Tags: java

I need to know what is the problem in the following code

```
public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        while (true) {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);
            Socket c = ss.accept();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
            String temp;

            // read browser Request
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }

            // send basic authentication request
            String response = "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"test\"\n"; 
            respons += "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\n";
            writer.writeBytes(response );
            writer.flush();

            // receive browser response 
            while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

when i request http://localhost:7777 from browser, the authentication dialog does not appear

why ????

also i'm tried to send this

```
  String response = "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\n";
                   response += "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"test\"\n";
```

also i sent full server response and without benefits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reader.readLine() will not return null until it reaches the EOF so you are blocked reading in the first loop and never send anything to the browser.

In the first loop look for an empty string or null.

```
while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if( temp.length() == 0 ) break;
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: I changed it, but the browser does not appear authentication dialog

Answer (score 0):

It works fine

```
        String response = "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"test\"\r\n"; 
        respons += "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n\r\n";
        writer.writeBytes(response );
        writer.flush();
```

but one one problem faced me, how to tell server to wait until browser send basic http authentication.

in my case browser request a new http request.

Thanks

Comment: This does not even compile... response <-> respons